# How do I merge B2C apple authentication with device-integrated xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-ad-b2c, apple-login

I have a b2c instance using custom policies and the identity policy framework

I have asp.net core, and xamarin.forms for iOS

If I enable apple authentication on b2c, how can I have an iOS device native authentication?

Or how could I adapt the GUI to use the local iOS api?

Comment: you are either using xamarin.forms, or you are using xamarin.ios. Anyone helping you needs to know which it is. Did you start by creating a Xamarin Forms project, or a Xamarin Native/iOS project? Do you write your app's UI once, in XAML, which could run on different platforms such as Android, or do you make UI in an iOS Storyboard? If its a Storyboard, then its like making any iOS native app in Objective C or Swift - you are just programming in C# instead (and using .Net Standard class library - but that shouldn't matter). Find instructions for an Apple language, and follow those.

Comment: While this doesn't solve the question you ask, [this blog post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/quot-sign-in-with-apple-quot-custom-policy-for-azure-ad-b2c/ba-p/766575) might help you find related efforts at Microsoft.

Comment: Did you already try? It should already be native with the built in MSAL web view. The user should be able to use Face ID etc.